# Page-object - How to select an item from a select_list with dynamic values using item index

Tags: watir-webdriver, page-object-gem

I have a select_list that gets populated in runtime. I need to select a value based on the item index.

Eg.

```
self.myselectlist1.option(indexval).select
```

If the indexval I pass is 3, it should select the third item.

The above code errors out. Is there an alternate way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `myselectlist1` is the name of a select list defined in an accessor, you want:

```
self.myselectlist1_element.options[0].click
```

Explanation:

1. `myselectlist1_element` is used to get the select list element.
2. `options` returns an array of option elements for the select list.
3. `[0]` returns the first item of the options array
4. `click` clicks the option to select it. There is no `select` defined for options (ie you will get a deprecation warning).

Comment: -> I just tried the above option and it worked! I did try it with _element but .click made the difference. Thank you so much!!!!! I also tried a workaround
`selval = self.myselectlist1_options[indexval-1] #index based on 0

self.myselectlist1 = selval`

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 issues:

1. The method you're looking for is "options" not "option"
2. Use brackets instead of parenthesis.
3. use click instead of select.

`myselectlist1.options[indexval].click`

Comment: I get a NoMethodError: and so I tried `myselectlist1.options[indexval].select` . Again it errored out NoMethodError: private method `select' called for "myselectlistvalue3":String

Comment: try click instead of select.

Comment: I tried a workaround and it worked!   
`selval =  self.myselectlist1_options[indexval-1] #index based on 0
self.myselectlist1  = selval`

Comment: Thank you Chags! .click worked with self.myselectlist1_element.options!